# href link to trigger asp.net c# button event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a navigation bar consisting of list items. Right at the end of the nav bar I want a logout link:

```html
//other links

...

<li>
    <a href="#"> logout </a>
</li>
```

I have an event in my C# code called `Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` that I want to run when the user clicks the above navbar link, but obviously ordinary `<a>` tags don't trigger ASP.NET click events.

So I thought I'd be clever and create a HIDDEN `<asp:Button>` called logout that does trigger the `Logout_Click` function, and then get the JavaScript to click the button for me.. here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logout').click();" class="top">Log Out</a>

<form runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="logout" runat="server" onclick="Logout_Click" Visible="false" />
</form>
```

But it still didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try without the Visible="false" on the asp:button?

And if it works hide it with css instead, style="display:none;"

Comment: Not really enough.. you better not rely the ID will be the final client ID and use `<%= logout.ClientID %>` to get it.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('<%= logout.ClientID %>').click();" class="top">Log Out</a>
```

Comment: Not enough.. there will be no button in the HTML source code because the server won't send anything due to the button having `Visible="false"`

Comment: @shadow is correct when page gets rendered browser will not be getting any element , i think you can use ajax to make a partial post back and call a server side function.

Comment: @ankur really no need for AJAX here - the accepted answer is what needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the script needs the client side id of your asp.net control:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('<%=logout.ClientID').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the __doPostBack function ...

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/[enter link description here](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not you are using Asp.net LinkButton ?
It's easy to do this work with LinkButton.